# Cron Job Rake Task scheduled through Whenever gem is not executing the rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have the cron set up as shown below in the schedule.rb file

```
job_type :rake, "cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake :task :output"
job_type :command, "cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment /usr/local/bin/backup :task :output"
job_type :ruby_command, "cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment /usr/local/bin/ruby :task :output"


every 2.minutes do
  rake "to_do_tasks:delete_tmp_files"
end
```

The task, however, is never executed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Currently it's unclear what you're asking.  Here is [a guide on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. Furthermore it also helps you solving the question yourself.

Comment: Did you find a solution?